# In Flow, how to assign ID field to sobject variables to build sobject collection to Fast Update?

Tags: visual-workflow

What I'm trying to do is in Flow query (Fast Lookup) a Task's `TaskWhoRelation` records, loop over them to build a new sobject collection of `Contact` records using the `TaskWhoRelation.RelationId`, then perform a **Fast Update** on the built up sobject collection of Contacts.

The part I'm stuck on is that the **Assignment** element does not let me set the `Contact.Id` field.

[image]

Comment: This is a bit confusing as to where you are in the flow (have you already queried for the Contacts)?

Comment: @cropredy, I have not queried any Contacts, only the TaskWhoRelation object. My goal is to not query Contacts since I already have the IDs from the TaskWhoRelation.RelationId field. Thanks

Comment: sfdcfox has it pegged;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a limitation of flows. The Id field is contractually read-only, and so the Flow system won't let you assign a value to the Id field. You will need to use a Fast Lookup or Record Lookup to first query the records you want to update. Even though we wouldn't do this in plain Visualforce/Apex Code (since we already have the ID values), Flows do not allow us to simply call into existence records that are already in the database unless we query them somehow. The alternative to this, which I feel defeats the purpose of using flows, would be to create an [InvocableMethod](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableMethod.htm) and a series of [InvocableVariable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm) declarations, and create the objects in Apex Code.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox, I've resorted to an invocable apex class to parse the relations and return back list of contacts.